# What statistical test would be appropriate for this design?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I'm currently putting together a with-in subject, experimental study that has one IV with 2 levels (i.e. gender: female and male) and two DVs (salary and perceived competency score).

What would be a suitable statistical test to analyse the data collected?

Edit: Sorry, I probably should have included that. The research question is whether job applicants' gender influences the hiring decision from employers. The method of the study is basically where HR management practitioners will review a sample of resumes from applicants, and then give a competence score and award what they think is a suitable salary.

Comment: Depends on your actual research question. What are you trying to understand.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.